# How to write query to change SQL Server database mode from Recovery to NoRecovery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to write query to change a SQL Server database's mode from `Recovery` to `NoRecovery`?

Here I know the query to set Recovery mode

```
USE [master];   

ALTER DATABASE [DATABASE NAME] 
SET RECOVERY FULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

NORECOVERY is a option of RESTORE DATABASE to leave the database **non-operational** (do not rollback
uncommitted transactions) in order to do additional transaction log restore.

Below an example of RESTORE DATABASE with this option

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2019
FROM AdventureWorks2019
WITH NORECOVERY;  
GO  

RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks2019
FROM AdventureWorks2019_log 
WITH FILE = 1,  
WITH NORECOVERY;  
GO  

RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks2019
FROM AdventureWorks2019_log  
WITH FILE = 2,  
WITH NORECOVERY;  
GO  

RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks2019
FROM AdventureWorks2019_log
WITH FILE = 3,  
WITH NORECOVERY;  
GO  

RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2019  
WITH RECOVERY;  
GO
```

Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-transaction-log-backup-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

If you want change Recovery Model you can have 3 option:

**SIMPLE**

> No log backups.
> Automatically reclaims log space to keep space requirements small, essentially eliminating the need to manage the transaction log space.

```
ALTER DATABASE [DATABASE NAME] 
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
```

**FULL**

> Requires log backups.
> No work is lost due to a lost or damaged data file.
> Can recover to an arbitrary point in time (for example, prior to application or user error).

```
ALTER DATABASE [DATABASE NAME] 
SET RECOVERY FULL;
```

**BULK LOGGED**

> Requires log backups.
> An adjunct of the full recovery model that permits high-performance bulk copy operations.
> Reduces log space usage by using minimal logging for most bulk operations.

```
ALTER DATABASE [DATABASE NAME] SET RECOVERY BULK_LOGGED;
```

Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

There is no "norecovery" option.  I think you are looking for the "simple" recovery model:

```
ALTER DATABASE [DATABASE NAME] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
```

Comment: Documentation about various recovery models is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server

Comment: Daily I will get full back at 9:30pm,so once I restored it into db then I will read data for ETL.But after 3 hrs I will get .trn file.If I used NoRecovery mode while doing full back up I can't read data for ETL untill .trn files gets restored.My requirement is I need to read data once .bak file restored and also able to restore .trn file after 3hrs

Answer (score 0):

After execution of this query,can we restore .trn files into db

> ALTER DATABASE [DATABASE NAME] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;

Daily I will get full back at 9:30pm,so once I restored it into db then I will read data for ETL.But after 3 hrs I will get .trn file.If I used NoRecovery mode while doing full back up I can't read data for ETL untill .trn files gets restored.My requirement is I need to read data when db gets restored with.bak file and also able to restore .trn file after 3hrs